# imul instruction I get a different answer in AX comparing with emu8086

Tags: assembly, x86

So I have the following code in assembly language.

```
mov ax,0024h
mov bx,00A1h
imul bl
neg ax
push ax
push bx
inc sp
pop ax
```

I don't understand what third line is doing.How I started:

AX: 0024h, BX: 00A1h; now I have to multiply 0024h * 00A1, right? I get 16A4 but I in emu8086 program AX becomes F2A4, why?

Comment: `imul bl` is a signed 8 bit multiply. As such `00A1h` means `-95` and `0024h` is of course `36`. The result is thus `-3420` which is indeed `F2A4h`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!I got it but I don't understand how to covert from hex to decimal in 8 bit manually.I use the method from school and I get 00A1h means 161 but this is in 16 bit, right?

Comment: Yes, `161` is either 16 bit or unsigned 8 bit. There are various ways to convert negative numbers, the simplest is probably to do `x-256` so `161-256=-95` See also [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)